# Inserted from another table and get both table Id

Tags: sql

Sql:

```
    CREATE TABLE OldTable
(
    TaskId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TaskName VARCHAR(32)
)

CREATE TABLE NewTable
(
    TaskId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    TaskName VARCHAR(32)
)



INSERT INTO dbo.oldTable VALUES('TaskNo1')
INSERT INTO dbo.oldTable VALUES('TaskNo2')
INSERT INTO dbo.oldTable VALUES('TaskNo3')
INSERT INTO dbo.oldTable VALUES('TaskNo4')


DECLARE @MappingTableVar TABLE
(
    NewTaskid INT,
    OldTaksId int
);


INSERT INTO NewTable(TaskName) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.TaskId INTO @MappingTableVar(NewTaskId)
SELECT TaskName from OldTable 



SELECT * FROM @MappingTableVar

DROP TABLE NewTable;
DROP TABLE OldTable;
```

I would like to get mapping of OldTable's TaskId vs NewTable's TaksId.
I managed to get NewTaskId only.How can i get OldTask?

Need help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution be:

```
Insert NewTable( TaskName )
Select TaskName
From OldTable

Insert @MappingTableVar( NewTaskId, OldTaskId )
Select NewTable.TaskId, OldTable.TaskId
From NewTable
    Join OldTable
        On OldTable.TaskName = NewTable.TaskName
```

There is no way to get the OldTable's TaskId using the Output clause unless you include it in the insert (which means you need a column for it in NewTable):

```
Alter Table NewTable
    Add OldTaskId int 
GO

Insert NewTable( TaskName, OldTaskId )
Output inserted.TaskId, inserted.OldTaskId Into @MappingTableVar( NewTaskId, OldTaskId )
Select TaskName, TaskId
From OldTable
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if your TaskName is not unique then you could run into problems. The second method might be safer and you can always drop the column afterwards if you really don't have a need for it.

Comment: @Tom H - I thought about mentioning that when I wrote my post. Yet, if TaskName is not unique, that creates other problems. If say Task01 were duplicated in OldTable, by what logic are we claiming that (1,Task01) should be mapped to (1,Task01) in the NewTable but not say (2,Task01)? It is one the reasons why a unique key on something other than the surrogate key is so important.

Comment: I agree about the alternate key. My thinking was just that the table might include other columns that had been left out of the example or there might be foreign keys in other tables that link to the individual IDs, even if the task names were the same.